# Errors in Android

Tags: android

I am having an issue in android. I had a tutor help me with a android program i seen it work on his screen . when I imported the package on mine and tried to run it, it looks like this

[image]

I have no frigging idea why these errors are happening as I JUST seen it work on his. I am not sure what to post so I included this picture

EDIT:IT WOULDNT let me pos tthe pic so I put it on tinypic. IF you would rather have me put some type of code up I will but I dont really understand it at all as its not just a regular coding error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because you are not importing android.support.v7 library.
To solve this problem just

1. Right Click in your right project panel.
2. Select Import.
3. Search android.support.v7 in your workspace or in your android folder, android folder is in where your installed android sdk.

If this doesn't works, please, tell me.

Comment: Ok I did it, bu tit shows the app thing has errors now

Comment: Do you have TeamViewer?

Comment: Yeah I have team viewer bro

Comment: can you pass me your user and password to testeo080@gmail.com